# onClick add item to array

Tags: javascript

I have a list of product names in `PRODUCT_NUMBER`. What I need to do is when the user inputs a code number I need to check to see if it is a number and also check to compare it to the  `PRODUCT_NUMBER` to make sure it is a valid number and then if yes add it to the `orderProductCodeArr` Array. I am just not sure how to start this process.

```
var code = 0; 
var orderProductCodeArr = 0;
var quantityArr = 0

confirm('Do you want to add product to cart');

 orderProductCodeArr =  parseFloat(prompt('Enter input: '));

for(i=0; i<PRODUCT_NUMBER; i++){ }


PRODUCT_NUMBER = new Array('Salad Server Set', 'Party Serviette Holder', 
                'Tea Set', 'Mixing Bowl Set', 'Knife Block Set',
```

Comment: what ?! it's not clear what you want

Comment: What is PRODUCT_NUMBER ? You need to provide all the necessary parts of the code (which seems obvious to me).

Comment: @Virus721 I changed what I wrote to see if that made it clearer for you. Hopefully it has. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extract the item in your array based on user input, have this code:

```
var orderProductCode =  parseInt(prompt('Enter input: '), 10);
if (isNaN(orderProductCode)) {
    alert("input is not a valid number");
}
else {
    if (orderProductCode < 0 || orderProductCode >= PRODUCT_NUMBER.length) {
        alert("code does not match any item");
    }
    else {
        var item = PRODUCT_NUMBER[orderProductCode];
        alert("item is: " + item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, It is true about the language barrier, but it's my javascript which is my barrier. In the PRODUCT_NUMBER the list is in the product names, each seperated by a comma, so I am guessing I need do a count the length of the array for the actual code number.

Comment: Sorry still not clear enough. Can you post the code where `PRODUCT_NUMBER` is being defined and created or post sample value of it?

Comment: @ ShadowWizard I think what I am needing to ask, is I need to search the PRODUCT_NUMBER and match the input number. So I have to search for the number position of the product names stored in PRODUCT_NUMBER to be able to compare input number against it. Does this make sense.

Comment: Ok this is what I have so far `var start = confirm(CONFIRM_MESSAGE); if( start == true ){ var orderProductCodeArr = parseFloat(prompt('Enter input: ')); }else{ document.writeln('still to come') } if (isNaN(orderProductCodeArr)) { alert("input is not a valid number"); } else { ` This is where I need to search with in PRODUCT_NUMBER to see if the number the user inputted matches the position of any of the items listed.

Comment: PRODUCT_NUMBER is array of strings. There are no numbers. How can you match? I still can't figure what you are trying to do.

Comment: ok user inputs a number (code). So I have been given the PRODUCT_NUMBER with word stings. The code is the position of each string. So I user inputs 5 then it would match 'Knife Block Set' witch is the 5th string of PRODUCT_NUMBER. So what I am trying to do is do a check to make sure the number the user inputs matches one of the strings.

Comment: sorry the "Knife Block Set"is in position 4 . So a number of 5 input would return a nil result. I am really sorry that I am not explaining myself well.

Comment: thank you so much, sorry about it taking me so long to try and explain myself... will try harder in the future.

Comment: Start with some basic English terms. What you were after is GET item from an array, not ADD item to the array.